# Use Mac as media server/hub with iTunes

Tags: mac, itunes, music, media-center

I have an iMac that I rarely use anymore. About the only thing I use it for is to manage my ever-expanding music and movie library, and to sync all my iPhones and iPods and stuff. What I'm looking for is the best way to keep this up. I'd kind of like this iMac to be my personal server, so I can stream music to my PS3 or other macs, or whatever. I have several external hard drives, too. Should I store all my iTunes stuff on an external drive? Should I install Snow Leopard Server? What's the best complete setup here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For streaming music to your local network, you should look at apps like the [Squeezebox Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezebox_Server) or the [Firefly Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_Media_Server). If you run one of those on your server, any networked machine running iTunes should see the server as a local shared music store.

Answer (score 0):

[mythtv](http://mythtv.org) can act as a backend to serve video music and even live tv if you have a TV tuner card. I believe there are mac binaries, or you could install Linux on the mac (if it's an old 'un it would probably run better).

Comment: Yeah I want to keep Mac OS X. I have got the distribution of the media down, I'm just looking for any hardware suggestions or the like. Thanks though.